# Does "Malikul Mulki" have the same meaning with "Malikul Amlak" that is forbidden to use as name?

Tags: asma-ul-husna

My parent gives me the name "Malikul Mulki". I just know that Malikul Amlak is a forbidden name in Islam.

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The most disgraceful man near Allah is a man who calls himself (or likes others to call him) Malikul-Amlak (i.e., king of kings)."

[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

Does anybody know that my name is the same meaning as it? or I allow to use it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two sources explicitly state that is unique to Allah and it is forbidden to give it to any creation.

[Islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/128974/):  و**مالك الملك**، ونحوها من الأسماء التي لا تناسب العباد المخلوقين المربوبين المقهورين ـ فإنه لا يجوز تسمية .غير الله تعالى بها

[Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura1-aya4.html#qortobi) : و **مالك الملك** لا ينبغي أن يختلف في أن هذا محرم على جميع المخلوقين كتحريم ملك الأملاك سواء

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know Arabic, I am unable to translate it. If I use google translate I am afraid it will change the meaning. So, you mean that my name has the same meaning and I must change that?

Comment: The Arabic texts essentially mean what I have written in the first line. The name is unique to Allah and it i forbidden to give it to anyone else.